# How to integrate library into my library

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, cmake

I made my own library which use Opencv and other library. Here is the

```
CMakelists.txt of my library:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project("face_module")

add_definitions("-std=c++11" "-Wno-write-strings")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "*.cpp"")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "*.h"")
add_library("face_module" SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_include_directories(
    "face_module" PUBLIC "include" )

find_package(OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)

set( JSONCPP_LIBRARIES    jsoncpp curl )
SET(OpenCV_LIBS  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_videoio opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs )

target_link_libraries("face_module"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so"
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES}
    pthread)
```

I use that library and also Opencv in my program:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project("database_generator")

add_definitions("-std=c++11" )

file(GLOB SOURCES  "database_generator.cpp")
file(GLOB HEADERS "")

add_executable("database_generator" ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries("database_generator"
 "face_module")
```

WHen I use the OpenCV VideoCapture in my database_generator project, the webcam sed me black images. I don't understand why this happen. 
As you can see in the CmakeLists.txt of the database_generator I don't add Opencv library because it is also added in my face_module library.

What do I have made badly in the generation of my library?

Here is the main file of my database_generator

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cv::VideoCapture *video_capture = new cv::VideoCapture(0);

    if (!video_capture->isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Can't open camera " << 0 << std::endl;
    }

    while(1) {
        cv::Mat u8x3_image;

        *video_capture >> u8x3_image;
        std::cout << "lalal"<< u8x3_image.empty() << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("facedetector", u8x3_image);
        cv::waitKey(100);
    }
}
```

With the previous code, the camera send me normal images but as soon as I use a class of my library, the image sended by the webcam are black...

Edit:
I also try to do all in my library I just generate a executable (no library)

```
project("database_generator2")

add_definitions("-std=c++11" )

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "*.cpp"  "../module/database_generator.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "*.h" )
add_executable("database_generator2" ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_include_directories(  "database_generator2" PUBLIC "include" )

find_package(OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)

set( JSONCPP_LIBRARIES    jsoncpp curl )
SET(OpenCV_LIBS  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_videoio opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs )

target_link_libraries("database_generator2"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so"
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${JSONCPP_LIBRARIES}
    pthread)
```

I also have the same trouble so the problem is not due to the library generation.
I think it comes from the tensoflow libraries libtensorflow_framework.so  libtensorflow.so  but I don't understand why.

```
    libtensorflow_framework.so:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff575d2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7afda2b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7afd722000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7afd505000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7afd183000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7afcf6d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7afcba3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7afe7f9000)
libtensorflow.so:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc32ba1000)
    libtensorflow_framework.so => /home/xavier/Desktop/developpement/Network/pam_face_module/library/lib/tensorflow/./libtensorflow_framework.so (0x00007f0bc5a55000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0bc5851000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0bc5634000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0bc532b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0bc4fa9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0bc4d93000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0bc49c9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0bc9233000)
```

It is really strange because the imread function of opencv works properly but the VideoCapture send me black images :(

Edit2:
It is crazy, in fact as soon as I use tensorlow object the VideoCapture send me black images ... Could this come from the tensorflow library compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using libraries that weren't linked correctly, you wouldn't even be getting an executable.

This should help

http://answers.opencv.org/question/129659/i-want-to-read-image-captured-by-webcam-videocapture-and-write-that-to-some-external-file/